# setting up pipeline completion trigger for YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have setup the pipeline completion trigger as shown in the below code; it should trigger whenever there is a build in the specified source pipeline.

But I get an issue with the pipeline name:

> Pipeline Resource commerce-sanity-test Input Must be Valid.

code:

```
pipelines:
  - pipeline: commerce-sanity-test //facing error with this name
    source: Gekko.commerce_controller_service
    project: commerce_controller_service
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
```

Comment: Hi manjesh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the liberty of editing your question, mainly so that the yaml code would display nicely.

Comment: Have you double-checked the pipeline name "Gekko.commerce_controller_service" ? This has to match, precisely, what the pipeline is called in the azure devops UI.

Comment: yes, the pipeline name is correct. getting exception as : The pipeline is not valid. Unable to resolve latest version for pipeline. This could be due to inaccessible pipeline or no version is available.